Make custom geometry clickable in APS Viewer
I've added custom geometry (Three.js) to a web app that uses the Autodesk Viewer API from Autodesk Platform Services.
I'd like to interact with the custom geometry as I can with geometry from a loaded Revit model. I'd also like the custom geometry to be included in APS dashboard elements, for instance a data grid.
Can anyone please point me in the right direction?
Or is it simply not currently possible?

There is various way of adding custom geometry in the APS Viewer.
The documentation describes the Overlay method : Add custom geometry
which is great if you want to add additional things in your scene eg. bounding box, lines...
However this is just an overlay; these elements are not added to the scene hierarchy and cannot be selected.
Another approach is to use the Scene Builder which is described in the documentation Custom Geometry with Scene Builder. With this approach, custom objects can be hovered / selected and appear in the hierarchy.
Here's a blog article that can help using the Scene Builder: Custom models in Forge Viewer
